# Could not get customTableViewCell in cellForRowAtIndexPath after reload UITableView crashed only in iPhone5(ios7)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios7

My app is crashed after reload tableview.

And this was happened only in iPhone5(iOS7) device.

rest of the device its working fine.

The following type of error shown:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException'

Why does this crash only on iPhone5(iOS7)?

Please help me guys..

Thanks in advance..!!

Following is the whole crash report which i getting:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCell lblFoodName]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13274160'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x046e75e4 __exceptionPreprocess + 180
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x033b68b6 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x04784903 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 275
    3   CoreFoundation                      0x046d790b ___forwarding___ + 1019
    4   CoreFoundation                      0x046d74ee _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 14
    5   EatEasily                           0x000b9db5 -[HomeMenuView tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] + 58533
    6   UIKit                               0x0242fd2f -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:withIndexPath:] + 412
    7   UIKit                               0x0242fe03 -[UITableView _createPreparedCellForGlobalRow:] + 69
    8   UIKit                               0x02414124 -[UITableView _updateVisibleCellsNow:] + 2378
    9   UIKit                               0x024275a5 -[UITableView layoutSubviews] + 213
    10  UIKit                               0x023abdd7 -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 355
    11  libobjc.A.dylib                     0x033c881f -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 70
    12  QuartzCore                          0x01cf972a -[CALayer layoutSublayers] + 148
    13  QuartzCore                          0x01ced514 _ZN2CA5Layer16layout_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 380
    14  QuartzCore                          0x01ced380 _ZN2CA5Layer28layout_and_display_if_neededEPNS_11TransactionE + 26
    15  QuartzCore                          0x01c55156 _ZN2CA7Context18commit_transactionEPNS_11TransactionE + 294
    16  QuartzCore                          0x01c564e1 _ZN2CA11Transaction6commitEv + 393
    17  QuartzCore                          0x01c56bb4 _ZN2CA11Transaction17observer_callbackEP19__CFRunLoopObservermPv + 92
    18  CoreFoundation                      0x046af53e __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 30
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x046af48f __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 399
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0468d3b4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1076
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0468cb33 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 467
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0468c94b CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x0439e9d7 GSEventRunModal + 192
    24  GraphicsServices                    0x0439e7fe GSEventRun + 104
    25  UIKit                               0x0234194b UIApplicationMain + 1225
    26  EatEasily                           0x00003092 main + 130
    27  EatEasily                           0x00003005 start + 53
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

My implementation code in cellForRowAtIndexPath is:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCellHomeMenu *cell;

cell = (CustomCellHomeMenu *)[tblMenu dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellHomeMenu" owner:self
                                    options:nil];
    cell = objHomeMenuCustomCell;
    objHomeMenuCustomCell = nil;
}
```

After that any declaration like:

```
cell.lblTest.text = @"MyTest";
```

then my app is crashed in iPhone5(iOS7) only.

Comment: Can you post all exception (another line or two).

Comment: Can you post your implementation of cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: Why you wrote objHomeMenuCustomCell = nil; at cellForAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Its no longer use thats why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the solution of my above crash issue, but its worst i don't know how its possible.

```
if(isIOS7)
{

            cell = (CustomCellHomeMenu *)[tblMenu dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

            if (cell == nil)
            {
                [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellHomeMenu" owner:self
                                            options:nil];
                cell = objHomeMenuCustomCell;
                objHomeMenuCustomCell = nil;
            }
 }
```

I wrote the above line of code at twice in cellForRowAtIndexPath method and that issue is to be solved.

Please tell me if you understand that problem why it should be wrote in twice.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellHomeMenu" owner:self options:nil];
```

is supposed to return an array with the views in that nib file and then you get the UITableViewCell you need and pass it to `cell`

for ex:

```
cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellHomeMenu" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

This var `objHomeMenuCustomCell` is useless

Comment: Same issue after implementing as you suggest.

Comment: You need to set Class of the UITableViewCell in the identity inspector to be CustomCellHomeMenu

Answer (score 0):

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

CustomCellHomeMenu *cell = (CustomCellHomeMenu *)[tblMenu dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCellHomeMenu" 
                                          owner:self
                                        options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
```

}
   cell.lblTest.text = @"MyTest";